# MD5 password Login, not working

Tags: php, validation, authentication, md5

I'm trying to make a new Login/Register System. My users are able to register now but i cant get the information when they try to login

```
if(Input::exists()){
    if (Token::check(Input::get('token'))){

        $validate = new Validate();
        $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
            'username' => array('required' => true),
            'password' => array('required' => true)
        ));

        if($validation->passed()){
            // log user in
            $user = new User();
            $login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), md5('password'));
            if($login){
                echo "succes";
            } else {
                echo '<p>Sorry, logging in failed</p>';
            }

        }else{
            foreach($validation->errors() as $error){
                echo $error, "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This it the code why can't they login? I think it's something with the md5('password').
Because i always get the Error: Sorry, logging in failed.
This is the Passed()

```
public function passed() {
    return $this->_passed;
}
```

And this is the one for the login()

```
public function login($username = null, $password = null){      
        $user = $this->find($username);

        if($user){
            if($this->data()->password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)){
                echo 'OK!';
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
    private function data(){
        return $this->_data;
    }
```

i used to use salts but it took very long to generate one i i also don't know that either why that is like that i will also make soon an topic about that but for now i want to use MD5 just to make my other functionality.

Comment: Well, yes. `md5('password')` calculates the MD5 sum of the string `'password'`. Which is always the same result. Also, MD5 is not suitable in the context of password security.

Comment: Can you also share the code of `login()` method from `Validate` class, so it becomes easy to identify and also the `passed()` to understand it is not landing in wrong direction

Comment: Yeah, i already noticed that but i just edited the topic

Comment: please, don't use MD5 for hashing passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks as though you are using Laravel? or something similar.

Try this instead:

```
$login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), 'password');
```

or perhaps you want:

```
$login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), Input::get('password'));
```

The login() function seems to be already doing the conversion to hash with Hash::make